# How can i can wait to call function before updating the data in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have two API get methods.
The first is to check if the user is an admin.
The second is to call all the user lists.

But I am having a hard time calling first;
It always calls all the user lists before I check if the user is admin or not.

What I did was

```
 async mounted() {
            await this.getCurrentUser();
        }
```

and method to check if user is admin:

```
getCurrentUser(){
                Common.getUser().then(data => {
                    if(!data.admin){
                        this.isAdmin = false;
                    }
                });
            },
```

method to get all users:

```
paging: function (pageNumber) {

                vm.requestParam.page = pageNumber == undefined ? 
                
                var param = Common.param(vm.requestParam);

                axios.get('/api/users?' + param).then(function (response) {
                  ///

                    }                       

                })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error.response);
                    });
            },
```

and the data is:

```
data: {
            resources: {},
         
           'requestParam': {
                'id': '',
                'query': '',
                'accessLevel': '',
                'page': 1
            },`
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that promise chains are broken, so `await` has no effect. As a rule of thumb, a function that involves promises should return a promise that represents the end of its job. It should be:

```
return Common.getCurrentUser()...
```

and

```
return axios.get('/api/users?' + param)...
```

Callback-based `nextTick` can result in race condition. In case it affects other methods, it should be a promise, too:

```
await this.$nextTick();
vm.getResources();
...
```